# K&R Exercise 1-6 & 1-7: working with EOF

Tags: c, io

I'm working through K&R at the moment and I've found my first exercise that seems to be a good use for my first CodeReview post.

Exercise 1-6 - Verify that the expression `getchar() != EOF` is `0` or `1`.

Exercise 1-7 - Write a program to print the value of `EOF`.

I've completed both of these together in the same file.

I think I've understood the question here, but let me know if I haven't. I wanted to post here before looking up any sort of "official" answer so that I could learn some stuff instead of just "going to the back of the book".

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
        int c;

        c = getchar();
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF == (0 | 1)) {
                putchar(c);
        }
        printf("%d\n", EOF);
}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc putchar.c -o putchar
```

Sending EOF using:

```
<ctrl-d>
```

Runs through fine, and when I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> I get a `-1` return code.

Comment: I don't see the exercise but `(0 | 1)` isn't probably what you think it is. `|` is bitwise OR then it's equivalent to `1`. Now it then can be reduced to `getchar() != EOF == 1` which is again equivalent to `getchar() != EOF` (because `==` returns 1 or 0 and it's mandated by the standard).

Comment: Ahhhhh right yeah I've definitely misused it then! Cheers for that, I'll have a look over my code and make an edit! Thanks.

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? If I've done something wrong leave a comment and tell me what I've done wrong.

Comment: I think (but I may be wrong) that someone considers the question off-topic because code does not work _as intended_. I don't agree because close reason says (emphasis is mine) _"...working correctly, **to the best of the author's knowledge**"_ then this is a perfectly fine question.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti While that may have been true at the time of posting, it is no longer true (as the OP is now aware of the bug). It is also what might be considered an obvious bug (at least obvious after having encountered it many times before). OP, you can (almost) always [edit] your question to make it on-topic, once you have the correct solution. The only exception to that is if you have received answer (so as not to invalidate them).

Comment: @Graipher The code works, just not for the reason that the author thought. That misconception is perfect material to be discussed in a Code Review answer — no need to edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a nice, clear, short attempt at the exercise.

You've avoided a couple of common problems:

- You're correctly using `int` for the return value from `getchar()`.  A common mistake is to be misled by the name and to assign directly to a `char` variable.  That doesn't work, because truncating to `char` prevents `EOF` from being distinguished from a valid `char` value.
- You've correctly matched the `%d` specifier to the type of `EOF`.

---

One simple way to improve your code is to get the compiler to point out weaknesses for you (by default, most C compilers are very lenient; you have to specifically ask for more warnings):

```sh
gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wconversion putchar.c -o putchar
```

You can make it easier by writing a simple `Makefile` that contains just:

```make
CFLAGS = -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wconversion
```

And you can then build simply with

```sh
make putchar
```

When you've enabled warnings, you'll see:

```
198374.c:3:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
 void main()
      ^~~~
```

The fix for that should be obvious.

---

Now to the meat of the program.  Firstly, before the loop we have a statement

```
    c = getchar();
```

This consumes and ignores one character.  We probably didn't mean to throw that one away.

---

Now consider this expression:

```
 (c = getchar()) != EOF == (0 | 1)
```

We're actually comparing (after the assignment) `c != EOF` against `0|1`.  But `|` is the *bitwise-or* operator, so `0|1` evaluates to just `1`.  When `c` is not `EOF`, then `c!=EOF` is `1`, and the condition is satisfied.  The last time around the loop (when `c` becomes `EOF`), then `c!=EOF` is `0`, and the loop exits.

What we want to do is save the result of `c != EOF` and compare that to `0` and to `1` separately.  Or, even more simply for this exercise, just print it to standard output:

```
    do {
        c = getchar();
        printf("getchar() != EOF: %d\n", c != EOF);
    } while (c != EOF);
```

Note: given that we haven't been asked to copy the input to output, we shouldn't have the `putchar()` call.

If we really want to prove that `c != EOF` is always either `0` or `1`, we could test it automatically:

```
    do {
        c = getchar();
        if ((c != EOF) != 0  &&  (c != EOF) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "(c != EOF) was neither 0 nor 1\n");
            return 1;
        }
    } while (c != EOF);
```

You might choose to use a `switch` statement instead of the `if`; I think that's clearer:

```
        c = getchar();
        switch (c != EOF) {
        case 0:             /* okay */
        case 1:             /* okay */
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "(c != EOF) was neither 0 nor 1\n");
            return 1;
        }
```

---

## Modified code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int c;

        do {
            c = getchar();
            switch (c != EOF) {
            case 0:             /* okay */
            case 1:             /* okay */
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "(c != EOF) was neither 0 nor 1\n");
                return 1;
            }
        } while (c != EOF);

        printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the awesome reply! Means a lot, and the Makefile stuff I had no clue about, thanks for that, works like a charm. The `c = getchar()` throwing away the first character I didn't know about, but I had noticed that it was happening, had no clue why though!

Comment: "That doesn't work, because`EOF` is outside the range of any valid `char`." --> Not quite.  `EOF` often has the value of -1 and a signed `char` typically has the range of -128 to 127.  So having an  `EOF` inside the `char` range is common.  The "doesn't work" is due to `getchar()` retuning values in the `unsigned char` range and the negative `EOF` and these typical 257  different values are not distinguishable with an 8-bit `char`.

Comment: Oh yes - I hate these conversions between plain and unsigned char (such as with the `to*()` family of functions).  EOF does have to have a negative value, and I mistakenly assumed that it just had to be more negative than `CHAR_MIN`.

Comment: Why do we do this?

` case 0:             /* okay */
            case 1:             /* okay */`
And not assign a success for the case statements? Except for the 1 of course.

Comment: EDIT: Ignore me, I know why now haha. Because 0 is success so we just continue checking until EOF or an issue, hence the break on exit code 1.

Comment: Also, an interesting thing is that the `make putchar` returns a `warning: switch condition has boolean value`, and online people are saying this is probably a recommendation to use and `if else` statement instead of switch because it's a better standard, but in this situation we were doing it for readability, would you usually do it this way or was it as an educational example?

Comment: Just for the educational value - the compiler also knows what we're trying to demonstrate: the result can be only 0 or 1 (so the `default` will never be reached).  (P.S. sorry for late reply - just back from a weekend away).